# Purpose of Level Curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am learning about level sets and it was introduced by saying that a function with 3 variables f(x, y, z) will have a graph in R4 (4th dimension), which makes it necessary to have a way of visualizing it (using level sets).

Then what is the purpose of drawing the level sets for a function with 2 variables f(x, y), where the graph will be in R3 (3rd dimension) which can easily be visualized/drawn?

Comment: Have you ever seen a topographic (contour) map?

Comment: yes but I guess I understand the purpose of that more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you genuinely can visualize or draw a three-dimensional function accurately, then you're a better mathematician than I - I can handle $z = x^2 + y^2$ or something similar, but (for example) $z = x^3 - 6xy + 2x - y^2 + 4$? By constructing level sets, we can assemble a picture of something we can't visualize well. If I needed to, I could make level sets for $z = x^3 - 6xy + 2x - y^2 + 4$ by hand, and get a pretty good mental image of the surface.

Also, additional data can be acquired from level sets. In particular, the direction of the *gradient vector* is often difficult to spot by looking at a three-dimensional surface, but is easy to see by looking at a level set.

One last thing: Even if you can visualize a 3-D surface accurately, you can't get the whole picture all at once - this is the same reason we still use maps, even though the average phone is perfectly capable of displaying a 3-D image of the area. The point of a map is to see the whole region, without obstacles like buildings and mountains getting in the way. If you look at a 3-D surface, you'll often see that one part of it obscures other parts, and you have to keep rotating the image to get a sense of the whole thing. Using level sets, you can get a sense of the whole surface at once.

Comment: thanks, i was starting to understand and you explained well